# Update $scope.variable value after POST

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an simple TODO app using AngularJS, i POST the data to server when response comes, that response i want to store it existing variable and refresh the view. i.e

```
// This stores on page load, its working fine

var todos = $scope.todos = sever_passed_data;
```

but when i do,

```
$scope.$watch('todos', function () {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: my_url,
        data: $.param({todos_list: angular.toJson(todos)})
    });
    request.success(function(responce){
        var todos = $scope.todos = responce;
    });
}, true);
```

after this it gives me weird(**it goes in infinite loop and posting data to server**) output, i mean the `responce` doesn't stores in `todos` variable.

Comment: It looks as if you're watching `todos` on your scope, then updating it in the response, which causes another watch cycle, which updates it again, which causes another watch cycle, and on and on...

Comment: @MarcKline yeah i think this is what its happening, suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: First suggestion would be to place your $http/model stuff in services. That can help to keep you out of trouble. Then look at alternatives to using $watch. For instance, you could update the view as soon as the user submits, then manually trigger a POST and only rollback the UI update if there's a failure returned from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the returned value of the HTTP POST in the `$scope.todos` variable, you should use `response.data`. `response` contains the entire HTTP response, including the response code, response headers, response body, etc.

Why are you declaring the local variable `todos`? It will go out of scope as soon as the function exits. just assign `$scope.todos`. Also, you might want to use `then` instead of `success`. Here's an example:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url: my_url,
    data: $.param({todos_list: angular.toJson(todos)})
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.todos = response.data;
});
```

Comment: How to do that??
Can you please explain briefly, i am new to AngularJS.

Comment: tried above code but still it gives me weird output :(